# How do I interpret the WParam parameter of my image-scanning library?

Tags: delphi

I have a DLL for scanning images that sends messages to my application. The documentation describes it like this:

> If the trigger is pulled, the image data is sent to the DLL. WM_XFERSTATUS is sent to the host application with
>   information about the size of the image.
>   When the first transfer status message is received, the host application should provide a destination buffer for
>   the image by calling SNAPI_SetImageBuffer. After the entire image is transferred from the scanner to the DLL,
>   the application receives a Windows message indicating that the image data was stored.

The first message is documented like this:

> Message WM_XFERSTATUS
>   Description Image data is transferring from the scanner.
>   Table 1-1 Windows Messages (Continued)
>   Attribute Description
>   DLL Data, Error Reporting, Messages & Beep Codes 1 - 5
>   Value WM_APP+7
>
> Parameters
>
> - wParam – Pointer to DWPARAM structure (cast to DWPARAM *).
> - LODWORD (wparam) – The total number of bytes received so far.
> - HIDWORD (wparam) – The total number of bytes expected.
> - lParam – Handle to the device for which the message was posted.

The second message, for when the image is finished being transferred, is this:

> Message WM_IMAGE
>   Description Image data is available from the scanner and is stored in the buffer provided by a previous call to SNAPI_SetImageBuffer.
>   Value WM_APP+2
>
> Parameters
>
> - wParam – Pointer to DWPARAM structure (cast to DWPARAM *)
> - LODWORD (wparam) – The buffer status of the data stored
> - HIDWORD (wparam) – The length of the data in bytes
> - lParam – Handle to the device for which the message was posted
>
> Data Format Actual image data.

I use this code to get the message, but when I set the length of the data, an exception is raised:

```
type
  TScanner = class
  public
    Device: THandle;
    Connected: Boolean;
    ImageData: array of Byte;
    Pending: Boolean;

    procedure Connect;
    procedure Disconnect;
    procedure RequestSnapshot;
    procedure SetImageBuffer(Size: Integer);
  end;
procedure TMyform.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Devices: array[0..MAX_SCANNER-1] of THandle;
  NumScanners, I: Integer;
  Scanner: TScanner;
begin
  Scanners := TObjectList.Create;
  ScannerWnd := AllocateHWnd(ScannerWndProc);

  CheckSNAPIStatus(SNAPI_Init(ScannerWnd, Devices[0], NumScanners));
  for I := 0 to NumScanners-1 do
  begin
    Scanner := TScanner.Create;
    Scanner.Device := Devices[I];
    Scanners.Add(Scanner);
    // add it to the UI somewhere...
  end;
end;

procedure TMyform.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(ScannerWnd);
  Scanners.Free;
end;

procedure TScanner.SetImageBuffer(Size: Integer);
begin
  SetLength(ImageData, Size);   //Hear I get the error
  SNAPI_SetImageBuffer(Device, Pointer(ImageData), Length(ImageData));
end;

procedure TMyform.ScannerWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Scanner: TScanner;
begin
  case Message.Msg of

    WM_XFERSTATUS:
    begin
        Scanner.SetImageBuffer(HiDWord(Message.WParam));
    end;

    WM_IMAGE:
    begin
      if (LO(Message.WParam) and BUFFERSIZE_MASK) <> BUFFERSIZE_GOOD then
        raise Exception.Create('Image buffer error');

      // use Scanner.ImageData up to HIDWORD(Message.WParam) bytes as needed...

      SetLength(Scanner.ImageData, 0);
    end;
```

NOTE: I used the `HIDWORD` function but it is not working in Delphi. I replaced it with `HIWORD` function.

please how to get the IMAGE DATA

Comment: Is there missing something in your example, you are declaring and accessing Scanner in ScannerWndProc, but I can't see it has been created.

Comment: I didn't but the full code but  I created the class Scanner

Comment: I but only the part of code I have problem

Comment: This is based on code I gave you in [another discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664353), but it is NOT the exact same code I gave you. You have made alterations to it, which are in part causing the problems you describe in this discussion. And you have yet to provide a copy of `snapidll.h` to determine whether the original translation of the API was even correct in the first place (in particular, to resolve the discrepancy regarding use of `DWPARAM`/`LODWORD`/`HIDWORD` usage). Please don't start a new discussion when the previous discussion is still unresolved.

Comment: but you finished the discussion when you send me to ask Motorola for help, yes I used the   code you send it to me and I am trying to solve my problem even in another discussion.

Comment: @hythamgazmaty You need to slow down and learn some very basic skills. You have code that works. Study it. Inspect it under a debugger. Learn how it works. Then build up your code piece by piece. Start small. And build slowly. Make sure you have revision control so that you have a history.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks for your advice

Comment: @David Heffernan thanks for your advice and I am trying to build a code that help me but in this section I am not familiar with it but I will try to make it and if you can help me you and Mr.Remy Lebeau for solve my problem I need to do this in fast way. and thanks alot for your understanding me and help me

Comment: @hytham - A lot of times for now that you've been demanded what `DWPARAM` looks like. Remy asked you to provide `snapidll.h` and David mentions he has to guess what it could like. It's not possible to know what you're doing is correct or not if you don't provide information. You have to cooperate to get any help. 'DWPARAM' is just one example, you've been told multiple times that you're operating on an uninstantiated `TScanner`. Even in the updated code you have an uninstantiated local variable and you're operating on it. Listen carefully to what people say, and then respond.

Comment: What do you mean "any answer"? You have an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's very hard to work out what your question really is. At least some of it seems to revolve around how to decipher these messages.

You need to cast `wParam` to be a pointer to a `DWPARAM` struct. I don't know what that is since your question does not mention it. But you are not treating `wParam` as a pointer and that would appear to be incorrect.

My guess would be that `DWPARAM` is a struct containing two `DWORD` values. Like this:

```
type
  PDWPARAM = ^DWPARAM;
  DWPARAM = record
    Lo, Hi: DWORD;
  end;
```

So you can extract the two values like this:

```
PDWPARAM(Message.wParam).Lo
```

and

```
PDWPARAM(Message.wParam).Hi
```

---

Having said that, the [documentation that I can find](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/web/Business/Products/Bar%20Code%20Scanning/Bar%20Code%20Scanners/Fixed%20Mount%20Scanners/MiniScan%20954/_Documents/Static%20Files/5986003a.pdf) completely contradicts that which appears in the question. For example:

```
Message:     WM_XFERSTATUS
Value:       WM_APP+7
Description: Image data is transferring from the scanner.
Parameters:  wParam: total number of bytes received so far (cast to uint)
             lParam: total number of bytes expected (cast to uint)

....

Message:     WM_IMAGE
Value:       WM_APP+2
Description: Image data is available from the scanner and is stored in the buffer
             provided by a previous call to SetImageBuffer.
Parameters:  wParam: buffer status of the data stored
             lParam: length of the data in bytes (cast to long)
```

So, who knows what the interface to this library really is?

---

The problem that you report is that this line of code

```
SetLength(ImageData, Size);
```

results in an error. You did not say what the error was, so we have to guess.

The most plausible cause for an error is that `ImageData` cannot be accessed. That would be the case if you have not instantiated an instance of the `TScanner` class. And the code does indeed confirm that. You declare a local variable `Scanner` in `TMyform.ScannerWndProc` and never initialise it. The compiler would warn you of that if you enabled warnings. Or perhaps warnings are enabled and you are just ignoring them.

Anyway, there are two variables named `Scanner` in scope at the point where you use it. One is a member of the class, and the other is a local variable. The local variable is the one that is used, and it has not been initialised. You need to delete that spurious local variable.

---

However, by far the biggest mistake that you have made is your failure to report to use the information that you have observed. You have encountered an error and it's an unforgivable sin of omission to have failed to tell us what that error is.

What's more, you have not given us any diagnostics information. You have various variables in your program. You have not told us what values they hold at runtime. Perhaps you need to step back and learn some debugging skills.

The real solution to your problems is to learn how to gather and report diagnostics information.

Comment: Original whitepaper has LO<b>D</b>WORD and HI<b>D</b>WORD literally.

Comment: It is not work in C# they use this code to get the hi and lo:

Comment: ReadInt32((IntPtr)msg.WParam, 0) for lo

Comment: ReadInt32((IntPtr)msg.WParam, 4) for HI 
what can i used in delphi

Comment: Can you concentrate on the question that you asked. Scanner is not initialised. I haven't the remotest idea what those comments are about.

Comment: yes the Scanner is initialized but if you read the explain of the getting the image they told that i must setImageBuffer size witch i get it from the HIDWORD (wparam) – The length of the data in bytes

Comment: No, `Scanner` is not initialized. It's right there in the code in your question. It's not initialized.

Comment: Sorry I Update my example Code

Comment: in C# code to get the HIDWORD I used 
ReadInt32((IntPtr)msg.WParam, 4)

Comment: You still fail to initialize `Scanner`. It's a local variable in `TMyform.ScannerWndProc`.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do much more. The most important information is the final three paragraphs.

Comment: In the original code (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664353), `Scanner` was being initialized properly. This code has been altered from the original.